# rails4 mobile api using devise3.1.1 + Sign_out

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

```
For mobile API using rails 4 , sign_in and sign_up functionality is working in rest API Mozilla browser but for sign_out it is not working. Devise is not able to map sessions Controller Destroy method. following is my code:

in routes file: 
devise_for :consumers , :controllers  => {
                            :registrations => 'API/registrations',
                          }

 first we sign_in through :http://dev.demo.com/api/consumers/sign_in?user_login[login]=demo@demo.com&user_login[password]=demo1234
```

and get response :

```
{
   "success": true,
   "auth_token": "SgChaANPLC7ez53spDBJAw",
   "email": "demo@demo.com"
}
```

but when we sign_out: http://dev.demo.com/api/consumers/sign_out.json?auth_token=SgChaANPLC7ez53spDBJAw 
we get error :{
  "error": "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
}
How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply go to your database table of consumers/users, check in web portal the access_token field is created or activated when you login or sign up, when you sign out your access_token field should be either inactive or destroyed, 
                    So main question is how you are maintaining your access-token when you are login or sign_up, mobile api is always using access_token So, you need to set generated access_token in request header, and then user is logged in.

whenever user is logged  based on access-token in request header, you can easily destroy or deactivate access_token column of users/consumers table